# Perform calculation seperately on values from file in C++

Tags: c++

So I have a input file which contains several different integer values(each in a seperate line), now I need to read each value, find the square root and get the output. The issue I am having is that my code only reads the first value from the input file. I have a feeling I am supposed to be using a loop to read each value seperately, so if someone can help me out it would be really appreciated.

```
float file_inp() //reads values from file and calculates the square root
{
    float y = 0;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("input.txt",ios::in);
    if (fin)
    {
        int x = 0;
        fin >> x;
        y=sqrt(x);
    }

    return y;
}

int main()
{
    float y = 0;
    cout << file_inp();

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your feeling is correct. What happended when you tried to use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have a function that reads the file and returns *one* number.
No amount of looping can make that function produce more than one number.

Instead of one function that does all the work, it's often better to have functions that do a little bit of work and use them over and over.
It's also a good idea to separate I/O from data processing.

This the common "elementwise processing of whitespace-separated input" loop:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");  // No 'ios::in'; it's already an input stream.
    SomeType piece;
    while (input >> piece) // Read until you can't read no more.
    {
        process(piece);  // Do whatever you want to do.
    }
}
```

Adjust types and processing as necessary.

In your case,

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    int x;
    while (input >> x)
    {
        std::cout << std::sqrt(x) << std::endl;
    }
}
```